# How to use for loop inside <div> in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, for-loop

I have an array of image URLs. I am trying to make a dynamic bootstrap carousel that would automatically display all the images inside the array, whatever the length. I am trying to use a `for` loop inside the outer division of HTML code and then again using HTML code inside for loop. But, it gives me a parsing error:

```
Unexpected token at the start of for loop.
```

How can I solve this problem? I have tried using `forEach` and `map` too but wasn't successful. I am new to React. Here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Slideshow = () => {
  const image4 = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/2800/0*JrIbdP7jK-8hNwny.jpg';
  const image5 = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8e/2a/58/8e2a58243e9e5e6ed37928046aba64b8.jpg';
  const image6 = 'https://images.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/assassins-creed.jpg';

  const imgArr = [image4, image5, image6];

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id='carouselExampleControls'
        className='carousel slide'
        data-ride='carousel'
        data-pause='false'
      >
        <div className='carousel-inner'>
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (i === 0) {
                <div className='carousel-item active'>
                    <img src={imgArr[i]} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
                </div>;
                } else {
                <div className='carousel-item'>
                    <img src={imgArr[i]} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
                </div>;
                }
            }
        }
        </div>
        <a
          className='carousel-control-prev'
          href='#carouselExampleControls'
          role='button'
          data-slide='prev'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-prev-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a
          className='carousel-control-next'
          href='#carouselExampleControls'
          role='button'
          data-slide='next'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-next-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slideshow;
```

This is my Slideshow component and I am rendering it inside the app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

Instead of adding a for loop inside the jsx you can add a map and store it in a variable and use it inside the component.

```
const carousel = imgArr.map(function (image, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return (
      <div className='carousel-item active'>
        <img src={image} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='carousel-item'>
      <img src={image} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Full code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Slideshow = () => {
  const image4 = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/2800/0*JrIbdP7jK-8hNwny.jpg';
  const image5 = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8e/2a/58/8e2a58243e9e5e6ed37928046aba64b8.jpg';
  const image6 = 'https://images.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/assassins-creed.jpg';

  const imgArr = [image4, image5, image6];

  const carousel = imgArr.map(function (image, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      return (
        <div className='carousel-item active'>
          <img src={image} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className='carousel-item'>
        <img src={image} className='d-block w-100' alt='...' />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id='carouselExampleControls'
        className='carousel slide'
        data-ride='carousel'
        data-pause='false'
      >
        <div className='carousel-inner'>{carousel}</div>
        <a
          className='carousel-control-prev'
          href='#carouselExampleControls'
          role='button'
          data-slide='prev'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-prev-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a
          className='carousel-control-next'
          href='#carouselExampleControls'
          role='button'
          data-slide='next'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-next-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slideshow;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you put between `{}` in your JSX should be an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) (ie: something that evaluates to a value). `for` is a statement, and not an expression, so it doesn't evaluate to anything. You can instead use `.map()` on your array, which returns an array which you can then use within your JSX.

The fact that you're repeating your JSX code is also not good. The only thing that you need to change when `i` is 0 is the `active` class. Instead, you can add a conditional class to your div which make it so you don't have to maintain `carousel-item` in two places.

```
...
<div className="carousel-inner">
  {imgArr.map((elem, i) => 
    <div className={"carousel-item " + (i === 0 ? "active" : "")}>
      <img src={elem} className="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
...
```

Example below:

```js
function App() {
  const imgArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  return (
    <div className="carousel-inner">
      {imgArr.map((elem, i) => 
        <div className={"carousel-item " + (i === 0 ? "active" : "")}>
          {elem}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```